# Get value of checked box when select all is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

```
_____ _____________
name | select all o
----- -------------
abcd |     o
efcg |     o
qwer |     o
zxcv |     o
-------------------
```

when i click select all check box it should select all the check box and the corresponding all the values should be stored in a array[] like `[abcd,efch,qwer,zxcv]` using javascript.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's the code..? [what have you tried..?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: As per my understanding you are looking for this -  http://jsfiddle.net/HVXSp/

Answer (score 0):

Below function should be called by the 'onchange' event of the 'Select All' checkbox

Ex:

> `<input type="checkbox" name="select_all" value="select_all" onchange="checkAll()">`

```
function checkAll() {

    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('class_name_of_all_checkboxes'); // You have to give this class name to all checkboxes you want to check

    var checkbox_values = []; // If you need to access this array outside this function, then you will have to define it before the function

    for (index = 0; index < checkboxes.length; ++index) {
        if(!checkboxes[index].checked) {
            checkboxes[index].checked = true;
            checkbox_values.push(checkboxes[index].value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

select all code for check box

```
function checkAll(ckbAll) {

      var a[] = new array[50];
                    if (ckbAll.checked == true) {
                        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
                            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
                             a=$(this).val();
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
                            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
                             //do your logic to delete it from array
                        });
                    }
                }
```

Comment: @KarthikManoharan: OP wants js code for select all check box and unselect all and i have provide the code.and answer isn't in situation that one can down vote it